# Error "out of memory allocating" at compling passenger for apache in a VSP

Tags: c++, apache, passenger, openvz, openproject

I'm running a debian 7.0 (amd64) in VPS (OpenVz) 1GB Ram, 512MB SWAP and try to install [OpenProject](https://www.openproject.org/projects/openproject/wiki/Debian_Stable_with_MySQL_in_production).
But if I try to compile Passenger for Apache with

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

I get the following error message:

```
cc1plus: out of memory allocating 2048 bytes after a total of 5304320 bytes
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -fPIC -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/openssl -I/usr/include/xmltok -pthread -I/usr/include/apache2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -feliminate-unused-debug-symbols -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -Wno-attributes -ggdb -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAVE_ACCEPT4 -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_MAP_HEADER="<hash_map>" -DHASH_MAP_CLASS="hash_map" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Logging.o -c ext/common/Logging.cpp]
/home/openproject/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.41/build/cplusplus_support.rb:51:in `run_compiler'
/home/openproject/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.41/build/cplusplus_support.rb:61:in `compile_cxx'
/home/openproject/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.41/lib/phusion_passenger/common_library.rb:133:in `block (2 levels) in define_category_tasks'
Tasks: TOP => apache2 => buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so => buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Logging.o
```

I think that the problem is, that my swap partition is to small,but i cant set up more because of the OpenVz virtualization

```
 swapon failed: Operation not permitted
```

Has anyone a idea solving this problem?
Thanks guys!

Comment: 5,304,320 bytes, or 5 MB ? You definitely have an undersizing issue here.

Comment: Hm thats what the program output is saying. 5304320 bytes should be 5.3Mb ...

Answer (score 1):

You have to get a server with more RAM, or a server which does not use OpenVZ so that you can enable swap. Sorry. No other way.